# I need help about wordpress of members section

Tags: comments, members

```
    function yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle($content) {
  global $current_user, $post, $wpdb, $yg_yorumsuz_yazi;
  $mesaj = '';
 //Eğer giriş yapılmamışsa
 if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
   $mesaj = '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-login.php">Bağlantıyı Görmek için Giriş/Yorum Yapmalısınız</a>';
 }else{
   //Giriş yapılmışsa ancak yorum yapılmamışsa
   if ( (int) $yg_yorumsuz_yazi == $post->ID ) $yorum_sayisi = 0;
    else $yorum_sayisi = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = '%d' AND user_id = '%d'", (int) $post->ID, (int) $current_user->ID));
   if ( 1> $yorum_sayisi) {
     $mesaj = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'#respond">Bağlantıyı Görmek için Yorum Yapmalısınız</a>';
     $yg_yorumsuz_yazi = $post->ID;
   }
 }
 if ($mesaj) return preg_replace('/(<a[^>][^<]*<\/a>)/', $mesaj, $content); else return $content;
}
function yg_link_gizle($attr)
{
 if ($attr['title'] == "") $attr['title'] = $attr['link'];
 $link = '<a href="'.$attr['link'].'" title="'.$attr['title'].'">'.$attr['title'].'</a>';
 return yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle($link);
}
add_action('the_content', 'yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle');
add_shortcode('ygizle', 'yg_link_gizle');
```

i could show my links to my member witch write a comment but the thing is how could i do this to the place i chose

Comment: You don't honestly believe that anyone is able to follow code that has A) such a messy styling and B) is commented in something other than English...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you don't need a shortcode or a filter. Just paste your `yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle` function into functions.php and call it from any template file (they all reside in your theme folder) such as `single.php`, or from a plugin.

```
if(function_exists('yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle')){ // just in case
    yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle();
}
```

If you're only doing it in one place then you could even run your code inside the template file directly, without using functions.php. You need to modify the code in both cases to get rid of any `$content`-related logic.

Comment: function yg_link_gizle($attr)
{
 if ($attr['title'] == "") $attr['title'] = $attr['link'];
 $link = '<a href="'.$attr['link'].'" title="'.$attr['title'].'">'.$attr['title'].'</a>';
 return yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle($link);
}
i just need to loop with this cods otherwise the other section working beacuse of warning but this cod cannot be using where i want beacuse this cod using like [ygizle link=""] i have to change this like  [hide][/hide] this how can i do this by the way thanks for helping to me

Comment: Not sure I understand, sorry. Can you try Google Translate perhaps?

Comment: `function yg_link_gizle($attr) { if ($attr['title'] == "") $attr['title'] = $attr['link']; $link = '<a href="'.$attr['link'].'" title="'.$attr['title'].'">'.$attr['title'].'</a>'; return yg_yorumsuz_link_gizle($link); } `
i mean ,i have to change this code( [ygizle link=""] )like, [hide][/hide] this one ,my question is how can i do this.

for hiding wherever i want, where should i fix on this cod

Comment: Check out the code example in [this doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes).